# How to call a service in the - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation only once?:

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I had an application in which i need to call a service whenever the specified location change occurs.I had initiating the location controller in my delegate class, like this

```
    locationController = [[UILocation alloc] init];
    locationController.delegate = self;
    locationController.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationController.locationManager.distanceFilter = 1000.0;
    [locationController.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

But as everybody knows Accuracybest will call the didupdate methode multiple times in an inconsistent manner. so how can i call my service from the delegate methode only once?Can anybody point me how to achieve this?

Comment: writing [manager stopUpdatingLocation]; in didUpdateToLocation function will stop the next update

Comment: why dont u use a bool variable,initially set No then in if condition u  set bool Yes and call that method after that this will never called OR you can use stop updating location method

Comment: @ShehbazKhan but it is calling uneventimes

Comment: but as u said,u want to call your service once.so i think its fulfil your requirments.isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)postCurrentLocationOfDevice
{

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
   CURRENT_LOCATION = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    CURRENT_LOCATION = newLocation;
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
[manager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

It will stop location update when first location update occur.

Comment: icant stop the update as i need it throughout the application